# How to test devise after sign in path with Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

I am trying to test what happens after logging in through Devise gem.  For example, I have the controller to go to student_dashboard_path after users successfully login.

How can I test this with Capybara and Rspec?

I currently have this in:

/spec/features/user_signs_in_sees_dashboard_spec.rb

```
require 'rails_helper'

feature 'User sign in' do
  scenario 'successfully from sign in page and sees student dashboard' do
     sign_in
     visit student_dashboard_path
     expect(current_path).to eq(student_dashboard_path)
  end
end
```

and I have this in:

/spec/support/features/sign_in.rb

```
module Features
  def sign_in
    visit user_session_path
    fill_in 'Email', with: User.first.email
    fill_in 'Password', with: User.first.password
    click_button 'Log in'
  end
end
```

and I am getting this error message:

```
  1) User signs in successfully from sign in and sees dashboard
 Failure/Error: expect(current_path).to eq(student_dashboard_path)

   expected: "/student/dashboard"
        got: "/student/login"
```

I am not sure why I am not able to log in and see the student dashboard.

Comment: What is creating the User in your test and do you really have the plain text password stored there ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm leaving my original answer below for anyone still on Capybara < 2.5.0 but in 2.5.0 you can now do

```
expect(page).to have_current_path(<expected path>)
```

and it will use Capybara's waiting behavior while checking for the path

----  Below is only for Capybara version < 2.5.0

expect(current_path).to eq(...) doesn't wait for the path to change, it just compares to the current path at the time it's called.  If you put a sleep after the click button I bet it works.  A better solution would be to have something like

```
expect(page).to have_text('You are now logged in')
```

after the click_button. That would cause capybara to wait until the log in has completed, the page loads (and the logged in notice appears), and therefore until the current_path has changed too.

Answer (score 0):

Use capybara `save_and_open_page` in middle to figure out if the fields are properly set. If you work on the same machine you can switch to **selenium** to test out on the real browser.

Also be sure that this code does not need any JS to work because default capybara matchers will not be able to run it.